# Need help about Drag a sprite with Animation (Cocos2d)

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, drag

I want to play an animation when someone drag a sprite from it's default position to another position. Also when drag will be end, then the sprite will be restore to it's default position with first frame.

I am learning cocos2d from few weeks, I know how to make an animation but I have no idea how to do this. If someone can give me any idea or any tutorial how to do this, it will be very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zishan,
Here's a tutorial that I think will help: [url]http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d[/url]

Another non-Cocos2d tutorial is: [url]https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html[/url]